# Scroll example in ElasticSearch NEST API

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using .From() and .Size() methods to retrieve all documents from Elastic Search results.

Below is sample example -

```cs
ISearchResponse<dynamic> bResponse = ObjElasticClient.Search<dynamic>(s => s.From(0).Size(25000).Index("accounts").AllTypes().Query(Query));
```

Recently i came across scroll feature of Elastic Search. This looks better approach than From() and Size() methods specifically to fetch large data.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

I looking for example on Scroll feature in NEST API.

Can someone please provide NEST example?

Thanks,
Sameer

Comment: There is a "new" scroll feature, which can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55115517/how-to-get-all-documents-by-index-in-easticsearch-using-nest/55120639#55120639

Answer (score 27):

Here's an example of using scroll with NEST and C#.  Works with 5.x and 6.x

```cs
public IEnumerable<T> GetAllDocumentsInIndex<T>(string indexName, string scrollTimeout = "2m", int scrollSize = 1000) where T : class
      {
          ISearchResponse<T> initialResponse = this.ElasticClient.Search<T>
              (scr => scr.Index(indexName)
                   .From(0)
                   .Take(scrollSize)
                   .MatchAll()
                   .Scroll(scrollTimeout));

          List<T> results = new List<T>();

          if (!initialResponse.IsValid || string.IsNullOrEmpty(initialResponse.ScrollId))
              throw new Exception(initialResponse.ServerError.Error.Reason);

          if (initialResponse.Documents.Any())
              results.AddRange(initialResponse.Documents);

          string scrollid = initialResponse.ScrollId;
          bool isScrollSetHasData = true;
          while (isScrollSetHasData)
          {
              ISearchResponse<T> loopingResponse = this.ElasticClient.Scroll<T>(scrollTimeout, scrollid);
              if (loopingResponse.IsValid)
              {
                  results.AddRange(loopingResponse.Documents);
                  scrollid = loopingResponse.ScrollId;
              }
              isScrollSetHasData = loopingResponse.Documents.Any();
          }

          this.ElasticClient.ClearScroll(new ClearScrollRequest(scrollid));
          return results;
      }
```

It's from: http://telegraphrepaircompany.com/elasticsearch-nest-scroll-api-c/

Answer (score 7):

Internal implementation of NEST `Reindex` uses scroll to move documents from one index to another.

It should be good starting point.

Below you can find interesting for you code from [github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Nest/Domain/Observers/ReindexObservable.cs#l35-82).

```cs
var page = 0;
var searchResult = this.CurrentClient.Search<T>(
    s => s
        .Index(fromIndex)
        .AllTypes()
        .From(0)
        .Size(size)
        .Query(this._reindexDescriptor._QuerySelector ?? (q=>q.MatchAll()))
        .SearchType(SearchType.Scan)
        .Scroll(scroll)
    );
if (searchResult.Total <= 0)
    throw new ReindexException(searchResult.ConnectionStatus, "index " + fromIndex + " has no documents!");
IBulkResponse indexResult = null;
do
{
    var result = searchResult;
    searchResult = this.CurrentClient.Scroll<T>(s => s
        .Scroll(scroll)
        .ScrollId(result.ScrollId)
    );
    if (searchResult.Documents.HasAny())
        indexResult = this.IndexSearchResults(searchResult, observer, toIndex, page);
    page++;
} while (searchResult.IsValid && indexResult != null && indexResult.IsValid && searchResult.Documents.HasAny());
```

Also you can take a look at [integration test](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Integration/Search/Scroll/ScrollTests.cs#l10-44) for `Scroll`

```cs
[Test]
public void SearchTypeScan()
{
    var scanResults = this.Client.Search<ElasticsearchProject>(s => s
        .From(0)
        .Size(1)
        .MatchAll()
        .Fields(f => f.Name)
        .SearchType(SearchType.Scan)
        .Scroll("2s")
    );
    Assert.True(scanResults.IsValid);
    Assert.False(scanResults.FieldSelections.Any());
    Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(scanResults.ScrollId);

    var results = this.Client.Scroll<ElasticsearchProject>(s=>s
        .Scroll("4s") 
        .ScrollId(scanResults.ScrollId)
    );
    var hitCount = results.Hits.Count();
    while (results.FieldSelections.Any())
    {
        Assert.True(results.IsValid);
        Assert.True(results.FieldSelections.Any());
        Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(results.ScrollId);
        var localResults = results;
        results = this.Client.Scroll<ElasticsearchProject>(s=>s
            .Scroll("4s")
            .ScrollId(localResults.ScrollId));
        hitCount += results.Hits.Count();
    }
    Assert.AreEqual(scanResults.Total, hitCount);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.

With aggregation query query type 'scan' not supported. So is it still good to use Scroll without search type 'scan' ?

Comment: Yeah, but scroll will be less efficient https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html#scan-scroll. Depends on your use case.

Answer (score 7):

I took the liberty of rewriting the fine answer from Michael to async and a bit less verbose (v. 6.x Nest):

```cs
public async Task<IList<T>> RockAndScroll<T>(
    string indexName,
    string scrollTimeoutMinutes = "2m",
    int scrollPageSize = 1000
) where T : class
{
    var searchResponse = await this.ElasticClient.SearchAsync<T>(sd => sd
        .Index(indexName)
        .From(0)
        .Take(scrollPageSize)
        .MatchAll()
        .Scroll(scrollTimeoutMinutes));

    var results = new List<T>();

    while (true)
    {
        if (!searchResponse.IsValid || string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchResponse.ScrollId))
            throw new Exception($"Search error: {searchResponse.ServerError.Error.Reason}");

        if (!searchResponse.Documents.Any())
            break;

        results.AddRange(searchResponse.Documents);
        searchResponse = await ElasticClient.ScrollAsync<T>(scrollTimeoutMinutes, searchResponse.ScrollId);
    }

    await this.ElasticClient.ClearScrollAsync(new ClearScrollRequest(searchResponse.ScrollId));

    return results;
}
```

Comment: A couple comments: in `scrollTimeoutMilliseconds = "2m"`, `2m` means minutes, not milliseconds; see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#time-units). Explanation of what exactly this parameter does is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#scroll-search-context). You may also want to return `Task<ICollection<T>>` instead of `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` since the results are already in a List.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that correction, @TobiasJ. I have renamed the variable. As for ICollection it's probably even more descriptive returning an `IList<T>`, which effectively is an ICollection that can be accessed by index. Corrected as well

Answer (score 0):

I took Frederick's answer and made it an extension method that leverages IAsyncEnumerable:

```cs
// Adopted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56261657/1072030
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> ScrollAllAsync<T>(
    this IElasticClient elasticClient,
    string indexName,
    string scrollTimeoutMinutes = "2m",
    int scrollPageSize = 1000,
    [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken ct = default
) where T : class
{
    var searchResponse = await elasticClient.SearchAsync<T>(
        sd => sd
            .Index(indexName)
            .From(0)
            .Take(scrollPageSize)
            .MatchAll()
            .Scroll(scrollTimeoutMinutes),
        ct);
    
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!searchResponse.IsValid || string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchResponse.ScrollId))
                throw new Exception($"Search error: {searchResponse.ServerError.Error.Reason}");

            if (!searchResponse.Documents.Any())
                break;

            foreach(var item in searchResponse.Documents)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        
            searchResponse = await elasticClient.ScrollAsync<T>(scrollTimeoutMinutes, searchResponse.ScrollId, ct: ct);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        await elasticClient.ClearScrollAsync(new ClearScrollRequest(searchResponse.ScrollId), ct: ct);
    }
}
```

I'm guessing we should really be using `search_after` instead of the scroll api, but meh.