# how to get all documents by index in Easticsearch using NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to GET all my documents by Index. I have tried the following:

var response = client.Search(s => s.Index("test").MatchAll());

the response returns "successful operation" but it hits no document despite the fact that there are many documents under that index.

Comment: Hi, have you already tested the queries suggested in the official documentation (at [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html))?

Comment: `scroll` may help. check this: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/67fe8ce6cbaea8ab593dfe77d038fa5b6bb4f903/src/Tests/Tests/Document/Multiple/BulkAll/BulkAndScrollApiTests.cs

Answer (score 3):

To get *all* documents within an index, you'll want to use the [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html). Note that depending on how many documents we're talking about, it's likely that you'll receive them in batches through multiple HTTP requests/responses.

There's a helper in NEST for making this easier, `ScrollAll()`

```cs
Time processTimePerScroll = "20s";
int numberOfSlices = Environment.ProcessorCount;

var scrollAllObservable = client.ScrollAll<Person>(processTimePerScroll, numberOfSlices, sc => sc
    .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(numberOfSlices)
    .Search(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .MatchAll()
        )
    )
)

var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
Exception exception = null;

var scrollAllObserver = new ScrollAllObserver<Person>(
    onNext: response => 
    {
        // do something with the documents
        var documents = response.SearchResponse.Documents;
    },
    onError: e =>
    {
        exception = e;
        waitHandle.Set();
    },
    onCompleted: () => waitHandle.Set()
);


scrollAllObservable.Subscribe(scrollAllObserver);

waitHandle.WaitOne();

if (exception != null) 
{
    throw exception;    
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to add an async version I guess.

Comment: @RussCam How to set ScrollAll parameters: numberOfSlices, maxDegreeOfParallelism and size?
In some cases, i saw maxDegreeOfParallelism to be set as Environment.ProcessorCount and numberOfSlices being double of that.

How should they be calculated? Also, should they be related in any ways?