# How to stream many documents from Elasticsearch index (Scroll, Sliced Scroll)

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am looking for a way to stream all (~ 10^6+) documents via `.NET Nest Client`.
I want to boost performance by using parallel `async` requests. (e.g `ActionBlock`, `Task.WhenAll()`)

old fashioned without boosting:

```
  var objects = new List<object>();

            var searchResponse = await elasticClient.SearchAsync<object>(
                                     new SearchRequest<object>("myIndex")
                                         {
                                             Size = 7000,
                                             Query = new BoolQuery
                                                         {
                                                             //...
                                                         },
                                             // why here and in scroll itself?
                                             Scroll = "2s",
                                             Sort = new List<ISort>
                                                        {
                                                          //..
                                                        }
                                         });

            while (searchResponse.Documents.Any())
            {
                objects.AddRange(searchResponse.Documents);
                searchResponse = await elasticClient.ScrollAsync<object>("2s", searchResponse.ScrollId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            return objects;
```

then a try using parallel `sliced scroll`

```
 var result = new ConcurrentBag<object>();

            var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(
                id => new SearchRequest<object>("myIndex")
                          {
// hast to be lower than 1024?
                              Size = 1000,
                              Query = new BoolQuery
                                          {
                                              //...
                                          },
                              // why here and in scroll itself?
                              Scroll = "2s",
                              Sort = new List<ISort>
                                         {
                                             //..
                                         }
                          }).Select(
                async searchRequest =>
                    {
                        var searchResponse = await elasticClient.SearchAsync<object>(searchRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);

                        while (searchResponse.Documents.Any())
                        {
                            searchResponse.Documents.Each(result.Add);
                            searchResponse = await elasticClient.ScrollAsync<object>("2s", searchResponse.ScrollId).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                        // good idea right?
                        //await elasticClient.ClearScrollAsync(x => x.ScrollId(searchResponse.ScrollId)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    });

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks).PreserveAllExceptions().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return result.ToList();
```

But this only gives me a fraction of the actual available documents.
More over slices scroll is limited to 1024 documents per slice.
I was not able to increase this value to 7000:

```
{
    "myIndex_template": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "number_of_replicas": "0",
                "max_slices_per_scroll": "10000"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There’s  a `ScrollAll()` client method that exposes an observable for scrolling many documents: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/src/Nest/Document/Multiple/ScrollAll/ElasticClient-ScrollAll.cs. Here’s an example of how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55120639/1831

Comment: Actually using ScrollAll() my performance decreased. I tried increasing parallelism and increasing query size but at the end the 'old fashioned approach' seems to be faster